# How many DPI does the T-Mobile G1 phone have?

Tags: htc-dream

I've got a G1 borrowed from a friend and I was wondering what is the DPI/PPI for this phone.

I tried to Google for that, but no luck so far.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specs at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Dream) it is

- 320 x 480 px
- 3.2 in (81 mm)
- HVGA 65,536 color LCD
- 180 pixels per inch (ppi)

Comment: Thanks! I was close :) tried the [Wikipedia ppi forumula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Calculation_of_monitor_PPI) and got 181.98366059124237 because [another site](http://technologizer.com/2008/09/23/tmobile-g1-vs-iphone/) mentioned it the screen is 3.17″